# qt5 add library "Qt5WebEngineCore.lib" but link named "Qt5WebEngineCore551.lib"

Tags: c++, qt

I use qt5.5.1 qml. I want to use webengingview to show some page. In main.cpp I add the following code:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QtWebEngine::initialize();
```

So I need to add some webengine libs. but when i add by qtcreator and build, it tell me this error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cound not open the file “D:\Programs\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013\lib\Qt5WebEngineCore551.lib”
```

So how should I solve it?

this is my main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtWebEngine/QtWebEngine>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QtWebEngine::initialize();
    ...
}
```

and .pro file is:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    Handler/htmlhandler.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model

QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.

include(deployment.pri)

HEADERS += \
    Handler/htmlhandler.h

unix|win32: LIBS += -lQt5WebEngineCore
```

Comment: what does your include look like? and your .pro file entry

Comment: in main.cpp i write： 
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtWebEngine/QtWebEngine>
and .pro looks like:

TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick
CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    Handler/htmlhandler.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

HEADERS += \
    Handler/htmlhandler.h

unix|win32: LIBS += -lQt5WebEngineCore

Comment: put that in the question pls

Comment: detail info was appended to the question

Comment: would be good if you can put the `deployment.pri` as well. Apart from that try `QT += qml quick webengine` and do `#include <QtWebEngine>` instead in your includes and remove the line `unix|win32: LIBS += -lQt5WebEngineCore` when you did that go to `Build -> Run qmake`

Comment: it works! thanks !

Comment: good, I've put it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try `QT += qml quick webengine` and do `#include <QtWebEngine>` instead in your includes and remove the line `unix|win32: LIBS += -lQt5WebEngineCore` when you did that go to `Build -> Run qmake`